# MySQL same table calculation wrong results

Tags: mysql

I am trying the following query for calculation/reporting purposes, but it is giving an error.

```
SELECT c.idx, c.club_name, s.sale_event_date, 
COUNT(s.*) AS total_guests, 
(SELECT COUNT(s.*) FROM sales s WHERE t2.qr_scanned = 1 AND t2.sale_event_date = s.sale_event_date) AS total_scanned_guests, 
SUM(s.rep_sale_commission) AS total_rep_commission, 
SUM(s.sale_commission) AS total_admin_fees
FROM club c
LEFT JOIN sales s ON s.club_id = c.idx
WHERE c.admin_id = 37
GROUP BY s.sale_event_date
ORDER BY sale_event_date DESC
```

The error is:

```
use near '*) AS total_guests, (SELECT COUNT(s.id) FROM sales s WHERE t2.qr_scanned = 1 AN' at line 2
```

Comment: @iBlue Question updated!

Answer (score 1):

You don't include the table alias in `count(*)`.

Once you fix that problem, you'll see that you have an alias problem in the subquery.  I think the subquery alias should be `t2` rather than `s`:

```
SELECT c.idx, c.club_name, s.sale_event_date, COUNT(*) AS total_guests, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM sales t2
        WHERE t2.qr_scanned = 1 AND t2.sale_event_date = s.sale_event_date
       ) AS total_scanned_guests, 
       SUM(s.rep_sale_commission) AS total_rep_commission, 
       SUM(s.sale_commission) AS total_admin_fees
FROM club c LEFT JOIN
     sales s ON s.club_id = c.idx
WHERE c.admin_id = 37
GROUP BY s.sale_event_date
ORDER BY sale_event_date DESC;
```

In fact, I don't think you need the subquery at all.  It looks like you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT c.idx, c.club_name, s.sale_event_date, COUNT(sales.club_id) AS total_guests, 
       sum(s.qr_scanned = 1) AS total_scanned_guests, 
       SUM(s.rep_sale_commission) AS total_rep_commission, 
       SUM(s.sale_commission) AS total_admin_fees
FROM club c LEFT JOIN
     sales s ON s.club_id = c.idx
WHERE c.admin_id = 37
GROUP BY s.sale_event_date
ORDER BY sale_event_date DESC;
```

Comment: its working perfect but last row results are...
`New Event | NULL | 7 | NULL | NULL | NULL`

Comment: @seoppc . . . You are using a `left outer join`, so you are getting all values from `club` even when there are no matching results in `sales`.  That might explain this problem.

Comment: the above result is fine because there is not row in sales table for this id, but why total_guests are showing 7 while there are not results in second table.. Please help

Comment: I think there is some problem with `COUNT(*) AS total_guests`

Comment: @seoppc . . . I don't fully understand the data structure.  Perhaps you want to count the ones that match in the sales table.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
COUNT(s*) AS total_guests
```

to

```
COUNT(*) AS total_guests
```

or to

```
COUNT(s.id) AS total_guests
```

At least that seems to be your immediate problem.

Comment: No, It was typo, i have updated the question, and still showing same error